# Visual Studio 2010 keeps telling me I have extension updates, but there are none

Tags: visual-studio-2010, updates, visual-studio-extensions

For about a month now, whenever I open Visual Studio 2010, I have been getting the toast message that "New extension updates are available."  (The wording might be slightly different, but you get the idea).  Yet when I open the extension manager and click on the Updates section, all I see is "No items found," even after waiting a minute or two for everything to finish loading.

This is getting tedious.  Without having to disable update checks completely (which I **will** do as a last resort), has anybody else ever run into this, and do they know how to make it stop?

Comment: I would check each extension's website for updates yourself.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll do that and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Found it.  It was the extension for Indent Guides.  They dropped support for VS 2010 in the latest version and pointed VS 2010 users to their CodePlex page instead.  Not very elegant, but once I uninstalled the visualstudiogallery version and substituted it with the CodePlex version (then restarted VS a couple of times) the issue went away.  Never a dull moment... :-)